# How to show image from Byte array?

Tags: asp.net, image

I have the code which returns image from function by taking input parameter as a byte array. How to catch that image & show it on aspx page with asp control. ASP control have imageurl property & not have image property.

Please reply....

Regards,
Girish

Comment: You may take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738020/bytearray-to-image-asp-net/1738026#1738026

Answer (score 0):

You can either write image byte directly into response stream - this can be done when image is downloaded - or you have to save it in some location that can be accessed by your application, then generate virtual path for it's physical path and provide url for page control.