# Writing to the screen after Response.OutputStream.Write

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a bitmap using the System.Drawing namespace and rendering as a jpeg to the browser with

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The rendered jpeg takes up the whole screen - and I want to make a div appear over the graphic after the graphic has loaded. Is this possible given that no html is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do that.

You could use an HttpHandler for your image, then have whatever you want below it:

```
<img src='imageHandler.ashx' />
<div id='otherContent'>
   all other stuff here
</div>
```

For more information on how to use an HttpHandler in this case see: [bytearray to image asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738020/bytearray-to-image-asp-net)