# How to display an image in a User Control inside a Web Form using Byte Array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, user-controls, webforms

Here is the code, the problem is that the image is displayed but after clearing all the page, i need it to be drawn inside the user control that is inside the web form.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["ObjHoteles"] == null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "select hotel first please.";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Byte[]> ArrayFotos = new List<Byte[]>();
                string NombreDelHotel = "";

                Hoteles Hotel1 = (Hoteles)Session["ObjHoteles"];
                NombreDelHotel = Hotel1.NombreHotel;

                ArrayFotos = Persistencia.PersistenciaFotos.FotosDeHotel(NombreDelHotel);
                Session["CantFotos"] = ArrayFotos.Count();

                Byte[] Foto = ArrayFotos[0];

                Response.Buffer = true;                
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                Response.Expires = 0;
                Response.OutputStream.Write(Foto, 0, Foto.Length);
                Session["NumFoto"] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                List<Byte[]> ArrayFotos = new List<Byte[]>();
                string NombreDelHotel = "";

                Hoteles Hotel1 = (Hoteles)Session["ObjHoteles"];
                NombreDelHotel = Hotel1.NombreHotel;

                ArrayFotos = Persistencia.PersistenciaFotos.FotosDeHotel(NombreDelHotel);
                Session["CantFotos"] = ArrayFotos.Count();

                Byte[] Foto = ArrayFotos[(int)Session["NumFoto"]];

                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                Response.Expires = 0;
                Response.BinaryWrite(Foto);

            }
        }
    }
```

I need to display the image where the user control is located inside the web form. Not in a new page.

I need to use a User Control it was specifically requested by my client.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738020/bytearray-to-image-asp-net

Comment: Great, don't forget to give me some upvote love

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
<img src="/imagehandler.ashx" />
```

and

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
    }
}
```

another solution to this problem is to put the image data in cache:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(id.ToString(), imageData);
And pass the key to the HttpHandler in the querystring, so it can fetch it from cache:

<img src="/imagehandler.ashx?img=<%=id%>" />
<!-- will print ...ashx?img=42a96c06-c5dd-488c-906f-cf20663d0a43 -->
```

Reference: [bytearray to image asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738020/bytearray-to-image-asp-net)