# How can I retrieve an image from database and display it in a repeater control?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to display an image from a database in a repeater control but I am unable to retrieve it.

I used the following code

```
<div id="photos" class="galleryview">
   <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"> 
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="panel"> 
            <img src="<%#Eval("image") %>" /> 
            <div class="panel-overlay"> 
               <p>description: <b><%# Eval("description") %></b><br />
          View full-size photo <a href="<%#Eval("image") %>" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>  
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater> 
   <!-- Strip to display the bottom slideshow. --> 
   <ul class="filmstrip">
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"> 
         <ItemTemplate>
            <li><img width="100" height="100" src="<%#Eval("image") %>" alt='<%#Eval("description") %>' title='<%# Eval("category") %>' /></li>
         </ItemTemplate> 
      </asp:Repeater> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you upload the images, store it and save it's path or as a blob?

Answer (score 0):

I think the image in your db may be bytecode.You may find a way to make the byte to a image 
you can see this [Retrieve image from database and display on ASP.NET without httphandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140729/retrieve-image-from-database-and-display-on-asp-net-without-httphandler)