# Retrieve image saved in database into gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, image, gridview

I'm working with ASP.Net. I have fileuploader in one web from and have Gridview in another form. 
I can upload image to the database from the first form and it saved in binary data field.
How can I show each item's picture in Gridview?

Also I have problem with using Handler.Is there any simple way?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  There are many tutorials for showing images in a Gridview out of a database.  Here is a duplicate question with code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738020/bytearray-to-image-asp-net

Comment: Thank you very much,this link helped me:)