# How to display byte[] in an image control in asp.net without using handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have byte[] array of my image but i am having a hard time in displaying that image in image control. I don't want to use httphandler because i'm writing all my data related code in Data access layer and httphandler is present in presentation layer.

My Data access layer code is

```
public DataTable CheckUserID(string UserID)
   {

       try
       {
           var cn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SGSDataBase_CN"];
           con = new SqlConnection(cn);
           DuplicateUser = new DataTable();
           con.Open();

           //com = new SqlCommand();
           //com.Connection = con;
           //com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

           //com.CommandText = "Select UserName from dms.Users_Table WHERE UserId = '" +UserID+ "'";

           string query = "Select UserName, Password, ExpiredOn, IsAdmin, Department, Image from dms.Users_Table WHERE UserId = '" + UserID + "'";
           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter();
           adap.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
           adap.Fill(DuplicateUser);

       }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }

       finally
       {
           if (com != null)
               com.Dispose();

           if (con != null)
               con.Dispose();

           com = null;
           con = null;
       }

       return DuplicateUser;
   }
```

Above function is checking that if the user is present, auto fill all it's data.

My code behind is:

```
protected void Txt_UserID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _objClsCreateUsers = new ClsCreateUsers();
        userdata = new DataTable();
        userdata = _objClsCreateUsers.CheckUserID(Txt_UserID.Text);

        if (userdata.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('UserID already exists')", true);
            Txt_UserName.Text = userdata.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            Txt_Password.Attributes["value"] = userdata.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            Lst_Department.Text = userdata.Rows[0][4].ToString();
            Txt_ExpiredOn.Attributes["value"] = userdata.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            Lst_IsAdmin.Text = userdata.Rows[0][3].ToString();


            //byte[] ImgArr = ((byte[])userdata.Rows[0][5]);
            //string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(ImgArr, 0, ImgArr.Length);
            //Img_CreateUser.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64string;

            byte[] ImgArr = ((byte[])userdata.Rows[0][5]);
```

As you can see i have used convert.tobase64string but it is just showing a thumbnail in the upper right corner of the image control.

Please suggest a method which can be used here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12645794/728795

Comment: @Andrei why i can't use that method with asp image control...????

Comment: @JitenderSingh, I am not sure why, never did it myself. Perhaps you could, instead of `Src` try setting `Attributes[`Src]` of the control and see if that works. But does this really matter? Both render as `<img>` on the page

Comment: @Andrei But if you look at my code i have tried using this technique with my asp image control but it didn't worked....i don't know why...????

Comment: @Andrei Is handler is the last solution for image control....???