# Asp.net c# displaying multiple images from single database record

Tags: c#, asp.net

Building my first .net application, so please be patient of my novice level.

I am collecting data from users and storing into SQL. Each record has several data fields and up to four images (yes causes very large records, but volume is small).

Now I need to be able to display those images back to a user. I want to do this using a page layout similar to below, but don't know how to implement a handler that can deal with this. The record the page displays is coming from a query string, with the only value being the questionID.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Submit_Detail.aspx.cs" Inherits="cs1.Submit.Submit_Detail" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:FormView ID="Submit_tDetail" runat="server" ItemType="cs1.Models.Questions" SelectMethod ="GetQuestion" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <h1><%#:Item.KeyObjective %></h1>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="<%#:Item.ImageFile %>" style="border:solid; height:300px" alt="No Image"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="<%#:Item.ImageFile2 %>" style="border:solid; height:300px" alt="No Image" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="<%#:Item.ImageFile3 %>" style="border:solid; height:300px" alt="No Image"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="<%#:Item.ImageFile4 %>" style="border:solid; height:300px" alt="No Image" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align:left;">
                    <b>Author:</b><br /><%#:Item.Author %>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>Submit Date:</b>&nbsp;<%#: Item.SubmitDate %></span>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>Stem:</b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.Stem %></span>
                    <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</asp:Content>
```

Current code behind for the page:

```
namespace cs1.Submit
    {
    public partial class Submit_Detail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    public IQueryable<Questions> GetQuestion([QueryString("QuestionID")] int? QuestionId)
    {
        var _db = new cs1.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Questions> query = _db.Questions;
        if (QuestionId.HasValue && QuestionId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.QuestionID == QuestionId);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }
        return query;
    }
}
}
```

Each image in SQL server has three columns for binaryData, ContentType, and ImageName.

ImageFile,
Image1Content,
Image1Name,
Image2File,
Image2Content,
Image2Name,
etc.

Comment: I cannot get this to recognize the code blocks correctly, don't know why,,, am indenting?????

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390983/convert-from-binary-data-to-an-image-control-in-asp-net

Comment: You mention a handler which I'm guessing you mean HttpHandler?  If you do, this might get you on your way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738020/bytearray-to-image-asp-net.  There's a good accepted answer which also covers the concepts of HttpHandlers.

Comment: Dan, When I use the answer with 22 votes I receive a couple of errors. On the <img tag the complaint is no src. on code behind it is Image does not contain definition of src. I placed code behind line in the page load section. Also the end of that line (ImageBytes) is not recognized. Tried changing ImageBytes to my field name, still no joy.

Comment: Both the links that Dan Dumitru and Phil Cooper point to have a similar very highly rated answer, but I cannot get it to work... probably missing something simple see my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

honestly not sure how many links and searches this took to find, but the article at this link [ASP.NET images from SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/445876/Auto-bind-byte-to-asp-Image) was able to quickly and easily handle the situation that I needed. All the code is in the aspx page, no (new) code behind. Here is the new aspx page code that is working to pull the image/s. Thanks everyone for the help:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <asp:FormView ID="Submit_tDetail" runat="server" ItemType="cs1.Models.Questions" SelectMethod ="GetQuestion" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <h1><%#:Item.KeyObjective %></h1>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image1" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile")) %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image2" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile2")) %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image3" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile3")) %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image4" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile4")) %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align:left;">
                    <b>Author:</b><br /><%#:Item.Author %>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>Submit Date:</b>&nbsp;<%#: Item.SubmitDate %></span>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>Stem:</b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.Stem %></span>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
</asp:Content>
```